# How to change below code from asp.net to razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to Razor page but have been working in aspx. This below is my code - please help me convert this to a Razor page:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) 
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs("C:\\e_data\\WorkPage\\IMS18\\ALBAB_Dynamic\\20008\\Case_Manager\\" + file.FileName);
    }   
}
```

I want to change to razor page code.

Comment: See this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use for uploading a single file and storing the path to the file in a database.  It'll explain the bits that Microsoft left out of it's docs (for instance the path to the base directory in .netcore2.2) Note that security is not much of a concern for me as this is a small company intranet... but there's bits in there about getting filename without extension, and you may want to store without the file extension for security reasons (or remove and then add your own extension):

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Kit = await _context.Kits.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

        if (Kit == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];



            string folderName = "UploadedOriginalBOMs";

            string OrgBOMRootPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, folderName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(OrgBOMRootPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(OrgBOMRootPath);
            }
            string sFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(OrgBOMRootPath, file.FileName);
            //  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


            if (file.Length > 0)
            {

                String cleanFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {

                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }



                Kit.PathToOriginalBOM = "UploadedOriginalBOMs/" + file.FileName;
                _context.Kits.Attach(Kit).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return Page();
            }



        }


        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

You'll notice that you can just use the same forloop as in your .aspx file.